# ScheduledExecutorService To Run Every Few Seconds

Tags: java, concurrency, timer, ejb

I am trying to use the ScheduledExecutorService to run every few seconds in EJB. However, it does seem to work. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong. I found this website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

I want to run some code every few seconds. I am not sure whether this is concurrency because I want to execute only on one Thread that runs repeately. Below is the code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartUp {

    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
         executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 while(true) {
                     System.out.println("i");
                     // after send an e-mail
                 }
             }
         };
         ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

This does not seem to run. What am I doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: You have configured an initial delay of millions of seconds (`new Date().getTime()`) and then you are cancelling the task before it gets a chance to execute.

Comment: I want to start the task immediately and then every one second to run repedately. I will take out the cancel method. What should add instead of new Date().getTime()?

Comment: `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Thank you. That works but what I would like to do is run the Thread every few seconds. So if I take out the while loop it prints "i" once and then it doesn't execute. Am I missing something? I need this to run repeately.

Comment: As far as I can see, the schedule will run every second unless the program terminates. Do you have a sleep() on the main thread to stop the program from terminating?

Comment: No, I don't have a sleep() on the main Thread. Should, I have one and if yes where and why?

Comment: So, is the container shutting down? If so, you'll need something to keep it alive. I'm not that familiar with how this is done in EJB.

Answer (score 3):

When using EJBs you shouldn't create your own thread pool, but let the container do that for you. You should have something similar to:

```
@Singleton
public class TimerService {
    @EJB
    HelloService helloService;

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("timer: " + helloService.sayHello());
    }
}
```